# MYSQL query - multiple likes

Tags: mysql

Stuck on this query. Obviously what I have below is wrong but hopefully it makes what I'm trying to do clear.

```
SELECT branch, 
SUM(price * quantity) as "Office" FROM orders WHERE account LIKE "0%" 
and 
SUM(price * quantity) as Personal FROM orders WHERE account LIKE "1%" 
GROUP BY branch;
```

I'm sure I'm way off here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` inside each sum:

```
select branch,
    sum(case when account like '0%' then price * quantity else 0 end) as Office,
    sum(case when account like '1%' then price * quantity else 0 end) as Personal
from orders
group by branch
```